# How to stop threads in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

What is the corrent way to stop threads in Qt?

Suppose that I have a worker (`LicenseChecker` class) and I want to do some actions every n seconds in the `process` member function. I need to do it indefinitely, until someone abort my loop.

```
_worker = new LicenseChecker;
_thread = new QThread;
_worker->moveToThread(_thread);

connect(_thread, SIGNAL(started()), _worker, SLOT(process()));
connect(_worker, SIGNAL(finished()), _thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(_worker, SIGNAL(finished()), _worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(_thread, SIGNAL(finished()), _thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(_worker, SIGNAL(newLicensesActivated(QVector<LicenseInfo>)),
                 this, SLOT(newLicensesActivated(QVector<LicenseInfo>)));

_thread->start();
```

What can I do to abort it?

The first idea that I came up with was to define the `sleep` function as the following:

```
bool LicenseChecker::sleep(int seconds)
{
    QTime end_time = QTime::currentTime().addSecs(seconds);
    while (QTime::currentTime() < end_time)
    {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);

        QMutexLocker lock(&_abort_sync);
        if (_abort)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

and to check the return code of this function in my infinite loop:

```
while (true)
{
    if (!sleep(5))
    {
        emit finished();
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And then on `MainWindow`'s close event I need to do the following:

```
_worker->stop();
_thread->wait();
```

where `stop` member function just sets `_abort` data member to `true`, but the application hangs on these calls.

What is the right way to accomplish such task?

Comment: Any chance that if you run your code that you get an error on the command line that you "can't move to thread" or something like that?

Comment: you can emit finished signal to thread to trigger SLOT function to stop thread.

Comment: take a look to the mandelbrot example (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-mandelbrot-example.html) in which the worker thread waits for either "process the next job" or "please, shutdown" flag.

Comment: Why are you even using a thread at all to check for the license? Is it a really expensive, blocking operation, or can it just be done periodically with a QTimer?

Comment: @ScottG Yes, it is an expensive operation that make several database queries. I wonder how to stop `QTimer` as I asked in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you call `stop()` from another thread (the main thread) but the worker instance is located in the worker thread. You can overcome this problem by carefully writing something like this to invoke a method from another thread:

```
void Worker::stop()
{
    // make thread safe
    if(QThread::currentThread() != this->thread())
    {
        this->metaObject()->invokeMethod(this, "stop", Qt::QueuedConnection);
        return;
    }

    REAL CODE HERE ...
}
```

Besides that, i would rather use a timer to fire every n seconds to do the licence check. Something like that (example of an database connection checker):

```
dbCheckerThread = new QThread(this);
dbCheckerTimer = new QTimer();
dbCheckerTimer->setInterval(CHECKDBCONNECTIONINTERVALL);
dbCheckerTimer->moveToThread(dbCheckerThread);
dbChecker->moveToThread(dbCheckerThread);
connect(dbCheckerTimer, &QTimer::timeout, dbChecker, &DbConnectionChecker::checkConnection);
connect(dbCheckerThread, &QThread::started, dbCheckerTimer, static_cast<void (QTimer::*)(void)>(&QTimer::start));
dbCheckerThread->start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Btw, I fixed this problem by adding `Qt::QueuedConnection` argument to the `connect(_worker, SIGNAL(finished()), _thread, SLOT(quit()));` line. Also, how can I stop this interval?